# memory address of a struct data item

Tags: c, assembly, att

Given the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
  char a;
  int b[10];
} elem;

elem s[100];
```

and knowing that s, i, and j are located in %ebx, %esi, and %edi respectively, how do I determine the memory address of

```
s[i].b[j]
```

?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't, without knowing how your compiler packs/pads structures.

Comment: x was unnecessary... I've edited the question. Thanks @KerrekSB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

- The address of `s[i]` is offset from the address of `s[0]` by `i * sizeof(elem)` bytes.
- The address of the member `b[j]` is offset from the member `b[0]` by `j * sizeof(int)` bytes.
- The address of `b[0]` inside an object `elem x` is offset from the address of `x` by `offsetof(elem, b)` bytes. You need to `#include <stddef.h>` for this macro.

You can write a C program to emit all the relevant constants and then use those in your assembly code. In any case, you want to compute:

```
s + i * sizeof(elem) + offsetof(elem, b) + j * sizeof(int)
```

Or:

```
ebx + esi * sizeof(elem) + offsetof(elem, b) + edi * sizeof(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

in `c` you can find like this:

```
typedef struct {
  char a;
  int b[10];
} elem;

elem s[100];

int main(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
       printf("\n%p",&s[i]);                
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
         printf("\n\t%p",&(s[i].b[j]));
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

output :

```
00443010
        00443014
        00443018
        0044301C
        00443020
        00443024
        00443028
        0044302C
        00443030
        00443034
        00443038
0044303C
        00443040
        00443044
        00443048
        0044304C
        00443050
        00443054
        00443058
        0044305C
        00443060
        00443064
00443068
        0044306C
        00443070
        00443074
        00443078
        0044307C
        00443080
        00443084
        00443088
        0044308C
        00443090
00443094
        00443098
        0044309C
        004430A0
        004430A4
        004430A8
        004430AC
        004430B0
        004430B4
        004430B8
        004430BC
        ........
```

Comment: I think the OP want the solution in assembly, not C.

Comment: OP needs the address relative to `s`'s address, not an absolute one, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

You can add offsets to the base address s. Only difficulty about this is to know that you can use macro `#offsetof` defined in `<stddef>` header to get offset of elements inside the structure:

> SYNOPSIS         top
>
> ```
>    #include <stddef.h>
>
>    size_t offsetof(type, member); DESCRIPTION         top
>
>    The macro offsetof() returns the offset of the field member from the
>    start of the structure type.
>
>    This macro is useful because the sizes of the fields that compose a
>    structure can vary across implementations, and compilers may insert
>    different numbers of padding bytes between fields.  Consequently, an
>    element's offset is not necessarily given by the sum of the sizes of
>    the previous elements.
>
>    A compiler error will result if member is not aligned to a byte
>    boundary (i.e., it is a bit field).
> ```

```
#include <stddef.h>

int s_i_j_addr( int s, int i, int j) {
    if( i >= 100 || j >= 10) return -1; // error
    return s + i * sizeof( elem) + offsetof(elem, b) + j * sizeof(int);
}
```